# Building a chat application for Asp.Net MVC website

Tags: chat, asp.net

I want to include a chatting functionality in my ASP.Net MVC Website. It is an online trading website (like *ebay*, *Amazon* or *Airbnb*), where UserA creates an Advertisement and UserB wants to contact UserA to inquire about the Ad. UserB should be able to message UserA through the website. UserA should receive the message along with a notification when it arrives. Both Users should be able to maintain the history of their messages.

I have been searching for an answer for the past few days and have read plently of articles... I have investigated options like [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr), [Pusher](https://pusher.com/tutorials/chat-aspnet/), [Applozic](https://www.applozic.com/), etc. SignalR seems like a very good option, but it seems like it still requires quite a bit of coding. My goal is to build this application by writing the min amount code.

I have looked into options like [Zendesk](https://www.zendesk.com), [Olark](https://www.olark.com/) but those seem to be for customer service communication. What I want is a one-to-one, client-to-client chatting systems.

- *Are there any out-of-the-box solutions (like [Slack](https://slack.com), [Jabber](https://fornever.github.io/Jabber-Net/),
  [Gitter](https://gitter.im/)) that I could include in my website (does not need
  to be free)?*
- *I have also heard of [XMPP Standard](https://xmpp.org/), and I know I can build a
  chatting Application using XMPP. Are there any out-of-the-box XMPP
  applications that I could use?*

Comment: Yeah! Thanks, now it should be "answerable". Besides, what you describe as "similar to facebook" is what most of those "chatting" services do. I have that with messages on Mastodon as well as on many XMPP clients – so nothing FB-specific :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is a great guide](https://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide/) which summaries most of the options.

In case of my application, initially, I looked at [ably](https://www.ably.io/), which is a nice, out of the box solution (it is not free), but eventually decided to develop my own chatting application using [SignalR](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/real-time), to save money.